# Gitlab Runner autoscaling on private server

Tags: docker, configuration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, toml

I'm trying to make Gitlab-ci in autoscaling, but i'm having this error :

> WARNING: Failed to update executor docker+machine for 0f8e3032 No free
>   machines that can process builds

config.toml:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
log_level = "debug"

[[runners]]
  name = "First Runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.test.com/"
  token = "token"
  executor = "docker+machine"
  limit = 10
  [runners.docker]
    environment = ['GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true']
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = false
  [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 10
    IdleTime = 900
    MachineDriver = "generic"
    MachineName = "auto-scale-%s"
    MachineOptions = [
         "generic-ip-address=localhost"
    ]
  [runners.cache]
    Shared = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you seem to be missing a [Machine Driver](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-machine-section) configuration. Gitlab Runner doesn't know where to spin up a new machine without that config.

Comment: And your concurrent is now set to 1?

Comment: Yeah i made, some changed, my docker was taking a file from cache that's why my configuration was not changing

Comment: Ok, well, this is a weird situation since you are trying to provision the machine you are running the autoscaler on with docker to run jobs. If you want to autoscale you should provision new machines. Preferably on a (private) cloud provider.

Comment: So i cannot do it this way with generic driver ? Because We are a very small team

Comment: No, I am afraid not. You should just configure this server as a runner (preferably docker for clean environments) and if possible with higher concurrency. Autoscaling only works well if you have dynamic resources at your disposal (as stated; a cloud PaaS platform)